# Knowing best model in Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I trained a model using CNN,

The results are,

Accuracy
[image: Accuracy]

Loss
[image: Loss]

I read from fast.ai, the experts say, a good model has the val_loss is slightly greater than the loss.

My model is different in points, So, Can I take this model as good or I need to train again...

Thank you

Comment: It's depend on what's your goal, the model you used, your loss function and the number of samples. Too hard to commend about this model with these two graph

Comment: Downvote because this is not a programming question. It would be better suited for https://datascience.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that maybe your validation set is "too easy" for the CNN you trained or doesn't represent your problem enough. it's difficult to say witch the amount of information you provided.

I would say, your validation set is not properly chosen. or you could try using crossvalidation to get more insights.

Comment: Total dataset is 1000, x_train is (800,32) y_train is (200,32) y_train is (800,10) and y_test is (200, 10).

Answer (score 0):

First of all as already pointed out I'd check your data setup: How many data points do the training and the test (validation) data sets contain? And have they been properly chosen?

Additionally, this is an indicator that your model might be underfitting the training data. Generally, you are looking for the "sweet spot" regarding the trade off between predicting your training data well and not overfitting (i.e. doing bad on the test data):

[image]

If accuracy on the training data is not high then you might be underfitting (left hand side of the green dashed line). And doing worse on the training data than on the test data is an indication for that (although this case is not being shown in the plot). Therefore, I'd check what happens to your accuracy if you increase the model complexity and fit it better to the training data (moving towards the 'sweet spot' in the illustrative graph).

In contrast if your test data accuracy was low you might be in an overfitting situation (right hand side the green dashed line).